# How to configure Daily Cap on Application Insights in ARM or bicep?

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I created a new Log Analytics Workspace in the Azure Portal and manually set a Daily Cap of 5 GB/day. Next I created a new Application Insights resource in the Azure Portal which links to the newly created Log Analytics Workspace. I notice in the portal I can set a Daily Cap on the Application Insights resource as well, let's set it for the sake of it to 2 GB/day.

Then I try to export the ARM template and notice I get 4 errors:

```
{
  "code": "ExportTemplateCompletedWithErrors",
  "message": "Export template operation completed with errors. Some resources were not exported. Please see details for more information.",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "ExportTemplateProviderError",
      "target": "Microsoft.Insights/components/Annotations",
      "message": "Could not get resources of the type 'Microsoft.Insights/components/Annotations'. Resources of this type will not be exported."
    },
    {
      "code": "ExportTemplateProviderError",
      "target": "microsoft.insights/components/pricingPlans",
      "message": "Could not get resources of the type 'microsoft.insights/components/pricingPlans'. Resources of this type will not be exported."
    },
    {
      "code": "ExportTemplateProviderError",
      "target": "microsoft.insights/components/myanalyticsItems",
      "message": "Could not get resources of the type 'microsoft.insights/components/myanalyticsItems'. Resources of this type will not be exported."
    },
    {
      "code": "ExportTemplateProviderError",
      "target": "Microsoft.Insights/components/currentbillingfeatures",
      "message": "Could not get resources of the type 'Microsoft.Insights/components/currentbillingfeatures'. Resources of this type will not be exported."
    }
  ]
}
```

The generated template does not include any details on the Daily Cap. I guess it should have been part of the `currentbillingfeatures`. In the bicep template I also do not see anything related to Daily Cap (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.insights/components?pivots=deployment-language-bicep).

How can I set the Daily Cap on Application Insights using bicep?

Comment: Is ARM template works for you or only bicep? And also check [`microsoft.insights/components/pricingPlans`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.insights/components/pricingplans?pivots=deployment-language-bicep), `cap` property if that meets your requirement. @DeMaki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your requirement using bicep, you need to use [Microsoft. Insights/components/pricingPlans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.insights/components/pricingplans?pivots=deployment-language-bicep) resource because `Microsoft.insights/components/CurrentBillingFeatures` is not supported in bicep anymore. If ARM template works for your environment, then you can proceed with the current billing features insights resource as you used.

Reference [ARM template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/powershell#create-application-insights-resources-by-using-an-arm-template) to configure the Daily cap using billing features resource.

And coming to your requirement, use `pricing plan` resource as explained above, I was able to deploy it successfully without any issues.

1. *Created a log analytics resource as well as an application insights component as shown below using bicep.*

```bash
param resourceworkspace string = 'newtodayws'
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param appsight string = 'newtodaysight'
resource logAnalytics 'Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces@2021-12-01-preview' = {
  name: resourceworkspace
  location: location
  properties: {
    sku: {
      name: 'PerGB2018'
    }
    retentionInDays: 90
    workspaceCapping: {
      dailyQuotaGb: 5
    }
  }
}

resource applicationInsights 'Microsoft.Insights/components@2020-02-02' = {
  name: appsight
  location: location
  kind: 'web'
  properties: {
    Application_Type: 'web'
    WorkspaceResourceId: logAnalytics.id
  }
}
```

2. Once it is created, set up a daily volume cap limit using `Microsoft.Insights/components/pricingPlans` in bicep.

```bash
@description('Daily quota in GB.')
@minValue(1)
param dailyQuota int = 5
param warningThreshold int = 90
param appsight string = 'newtodaysight'

resource app 'Microsoft.Insights/components@2020-02-02' existing = {
  name: appsight
}

resource pricingplan 'Microsoft.Insights/components/pricingPlans@2017-10-01' = {
  name: 'current'
  parent: app
  properties: {
    cap: dailyQuota
    planType: 'Basic'
    stopSendNotificationWhenHitCap: true
    warningThreshold: warningThreshold
    }
  }
```

***Deployment succeeded:***

[image]

[image]